Помогите с диснейк
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="n.", help_command=None, intents=disnake.Intents.all())

BAD_WORDS = ['Fuck']

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online!")

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = await disnake.utils.get(guild_id=member.guild.id, role_id=1260954402509029469)
    channel = member.guild.system_channel()

    embed = disnake.embed(
        title = 'Welcome',
        describtion = f"{member_name}"


    )


    await member.add_roles(role)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    for content in message.content.split():
        for bad_words in BAD_WORDS:
            if content == bad_words:
                await message.delete()
                await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}Are you stupid? Dont use ban bad words')

Мне пишет:
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Дискорд боты\nostra.py", line 34, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}Are you stupid? Dont use ban bad words')
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'send'


on_message() принимает аргумент типа disnake.Message, поэтому вам выдаётся ошибка AttributeError.
Попробуйте получить канал и именно через него вызывать метод send():
await message.delete()
channel = bot.get_channel(message.channel.id)
await channel.send(f'Ваш текст')

